# UI grid how to export data to csv without displaying data on UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am new to angular UI grid , want to find out if there is a way that I could export data in UI grid to csvn, on a button click without displaying same data on the grid/screen . So essentially user will not see results on the UI but downloads excel directly

Answer (score 0):

Using alasql it is possible to generate xlsx/csv file.

If the records are in JSON format then on click of button, file can be generated-

alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("DatabaseLogs.xlsx",{headers:true,sheetid:"ExportData"}) FROM ?', [$scope.records]);

Here $scope.records contain data list in json format.

script(type='text/javascript',src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.2/alasql.min.js')

Comment: Do not have access to this dependency in the environment I am working ? , any other alternative options

Comment: I think the link is not accessible in your environment. You can use plugin by installing it. 'https://github.com/agershun/alasql'.
If you are using bower or npm to install the dependency : bower/npm install alasql .  

If this doesn't work then you can try ngCSV plugin 'http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv'.